# .NET Library for merging files

Tags: .net, file-comparison

Do You know any .net library that can be used for comparing and especially merging of two files (like .pst) - would be the best if open-source or inexpensive.

Comment: What kind of files?  Text files?

Comment: You will have a hard time finding something for PST files -- it's not a fun format to work with.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some implementations

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/diffengine.aspx

  - written some time ago but is entirely public domain
- http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/

  - Based on Eugene Myers classic algorithm. currently BSD licensed
  - Also old but the algorithm and implementation are well established and stable
- http://www.menees.com/DiffDotNet.htm

  - as an application, though it defers almost all the diff logic to a simple library so would be a good example of the libraries use.

I would suggest starting with the Myers implementation since it is based on a well reasoned algorithm and so if there is a bug you are likely to be able to identify it against some other reference implementation.